# My employer is pushing me to leave during probation?

Tags: probation

I was having regular days at work, till one day, I felt some miscommunication passed with my boss.

Since them, some new measures were taken (some internet websites were restricted, I was assigned a smaller project ...).

And, recently, my probation was extended.

My gut tells me something is wrong. Sometimes my boss is treating me well, some other times, I feel she's avoiding me or something.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information and context around what you are asking.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Can you tell us which sites you were visiting and how they relate to your work? - Can you describe the length or difficulty level of your prior projects compared to your current assignment? - Can you tell us if you think your boss avoids you because of  something you've done or is it related to the amount of time she has to spend with you? -- IF it was bad enough you'd be terminated, not offered to redeem yourself.

Comment: Did your boss give any reason for extending your probation or changing your project, or give any feedback whatsoever regarding your overall performance? If not, you really should ask. Having your probation extended is not a good sign, to the point that you should probably start working extra hard and looking for another job, but that's fairly logical - they're literally saying they need more time to decide if they want you. But the other things could be coincidental or you reading too much into things.

Comment: Have you already tried asking your boss ?

Answer (score 7):

**Short Answer:** Why would they?

If they didn't want you, they would have finished you up at the end of probation.  It sounds more like they are trying to give you a little more time to show that the miscommunication was an aberration rather than a trend.  Consider this a gift as it seems like they don't really want to let you go, but need to be sure that you are going to be an effective part of their organisation.

The reduction in permissions and responsibility and your boss's attitude towards you shows you that you have to work a bit harder at regaining trust.  Just do your job to the best of your ability but recognise that you may be on thin ice here.  It may be worthwhile keeping your CV up to date just in case, but try not to invite disaster when the situation may well be still salvageable.

Comment: I have figured out many things since last week: Many weeks ago, I had to spend a morning in my hometown due to some paper work, my boss most convinced I had a job interview (that's when problems started), she then decided to restrict internet, and force me to make the other departments tour and see how seriously I would take it. Anyway, I stopped responding to job offers and, suddenly, connection was back. I am a bit skeptic though: I still feel my boss is not very happy with me and gave me this extended period to make a graceful transition and not to harm my career.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking it wrong.

There is no good reason to extend your probation if they do not want to keep you.  They would've fired you instead.

You're not in the clear, but you're also not a lost cause.  You need to figure out what you are doing wrong and fix it.